# Python distinct list of from given attribute is a list of objects

Tags: python

I haven't been able to find this anywhere else.
I have

```
lst = [
  {'n':'Ste', ...}
  ,{'n':'Mil', ...}
  ,{'n':'Tob', ...}
  ,{'n':'', ...}
  ,{'n':'Ste', ...}
  ,{'n':'Mil', ...}
]
```

How can I reduce this to a distinct

```
['Ste','Tob','Mil','']
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called set comprehension

```
{ l['n'] for l in lst }
```

Comment: Thanks.  It is really simple once you see it.

Comment: note that it needs to be converted back to a list if you want to respect OP output (but that's minor since order is not guaranteed by the dictionary at start!). A little more explanation would be good, but still good answer.

Comment: Drop a line of code to show what you are thinking of?

Comment: just `list({ l['n'] for l in lst })`. But really, minor, as I said.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre My final had to be `list(set({ l['n'] for l in lst }))` which surprised me.  I thought it was already a set. So for some reason I had to make a set of a set before I could convert it to a list?

Comment: `list({ l['n'] for l in lst })` works fine. `{...}` is a `set` already, no need to create another one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the user needs a list.

`list({ l['n'] for l in lst })`

p.s. this would've been a comment if i had enough reps.

Comment: You are correct.  I drew the desired as a list.  But list, set, other.  ot me it is more about the distinct.  Thanks.

Comment: you'll be able to comment when you have enough rep. That said, it won't be with useless answers like that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  alright. wont forget. although i dont see it as useless. maybe its just my perspective and not yours. thanks.